# Constraintlayout - place textview beneath imageview causing unexpected grows

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I want to have 4 images that takes up the parent's width and the images should divide the total width by 4 with some offset. This is what it looks like:

[image]

Now I want to place four textlabels beneath them. Each ImageView should have a textlabel beneath it. This is the problem: when I try to center a TextView, 1 of the 4 images just randomly grows. I can not set the images to have all equal width/heights.

This is what it should look like:

[image]

How can I place and center the TextViews beneath the ImageViews? This is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="xxx">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Textview"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/website"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/website"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView12"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView12"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/website"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView11"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView3" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView11"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/website"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView12"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView10"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView12"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView12" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView10"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/website"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView11"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView11"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView11" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain `TextView` widgets the same way you did with image views.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/iv2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/iv3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/iv1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/iv1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/iv4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/iv2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/iv1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/iv3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/iv1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Textview"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tv2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/iv1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Textview"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tv3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tv1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tv1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Textview"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tv4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tv2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tv1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Textview"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tv3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tv1" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Don't forget to add this line to your gradle build file

```
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta3'
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can not test it right now but wouldn’t the textviews change from position if 1 textview has more characters inside of it, causing it to grow and pushes the other textviews away? Would every textview stay in the center of the imageview above regardless of the text inside other textviews?

Comment: They will never get bigger than ImageViews.

Answer (score 1):

For the results shown in above image, the most easy way is doing it like this ,

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/frame_2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:background="#eee" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Text1" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/frame_1"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/frame_3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:background="#eee" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Text2" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/frame_2"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/frame_4"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:background="#eee" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Text3" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_4"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/frame_3"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:background="#eee" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Text4" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks your answer :) However I want to use ConstraintLayout only. Thansk anyway!